# How to use proper MVVM to pass data in different content page Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I tried to pass values between two content page - MainPage and Page1 in my Xamarin app but no luck.Here is my MainPage.xaml

```
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:FindPerimeter/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="A side here"/>
        <Entry Placeholder="A side" Text="{Binding Aside}"/>
        <Button Text="Next page" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

Button code behind

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page1());
```

FindPerimeter.cs

```
    public class FindPerimeter : ViewModelBase
    {
        string a_side;

        public string Aside
        {
            get => a_side;
            set
            {
                if (a_side == value) return;

                a_side = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
                Perimeter = Calculate(a_side).ToString();
            }
        }

        string perimeter;

        public string Perimeter
        {
            get => perimeter;
            set
            {
                if (perimeter == value) return;

                perimeter = value;

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        double Calculate(string a)
        {
            return 2 * double.Parse(a);
        }

    }
V
```

iewModelBae.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

and Page1.xaml code

```
   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:FindPerimeter/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Perimeter is :"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Perimeter}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

So I want pass Perimeter value between MainPage.xaml and Page1.xaml but it is empty every time.I think it is because i create anther BindingContext in Page1.xaml but i dont know how to fix.The only way that i found is to make Perimeter property `static`.

Comment: pass the VM as a parameter on the 2nd page's consructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Binding the viewmodel of Page8 to Page9 like below.

MainPage:

```
  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var page1 = new Page1();
        page1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page1);
    }
```

[image]